# OpenFile Servlet from specified path

Tags: file, jsp, servlets, fileinputstream

I have a jsp that sends some form data retrived from a database to a Servlet.

Example:

```
PaperId = 5  
PaperPath = 'D:\upload\111\aaa.pdf'
```

How can I implement a servlet that uses this information in order to Open the file?

Comment: unclear what you try to achieve

Comment: I need to implement a servlet that opens the file from the given location.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the file location, then it doesn't matter if you have a servlet or a regular java app. Just use `FileInputStream` to read the file, or better - commons-io `FileUtils`